# required condition is false: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(hwFormat)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Our app is using SFSpeechRecognizer to recognize voice. It is working at our end but sometimes crashes at client side. We are getting the following error in crash report system:

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Reason: required condition is false: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(hwFormat)
...
AvAudioEngine.get_InputNode
MainViewController.ViewDidLoad
...
```

So as I see the crash happens in ViewDidLoad method when accessing InputNode property of AvAudioEngine. Here is the code from ViewDidLoad:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
 ...
  speechRecognizer = new SFSpeechRecognizer(new NSLocale("en-US"));
  audioEngine = new AVAudioEngine();
  //simply access the engine's input node immediately after 
  instantiation so that the engine is configured for audio input TO FIX 
  IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format) crash                    
  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903563/avaudioengine-inputnodes- 
  format-changes-when-playing-an-avaudioplayernode
  var input = audioEngine.InputNode;
...
}
```

Also here is methods for start/stop recording:

```
    Timer speechTimer;
    private async void startDictating()
    {
        try
        {
            stopRecognizer = false;
            recognitionTask?.Cancel();
            recognitionTask = null;
            await Task.Delay(1000);//https://github.com/wenkesj/react- 
            native-voice/issues/50

            //==== Make volume louder =====//
            var audioSession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
            error = 
    audioSession.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.PlayAndRecord);
            audioSession.SetMode(AVAudioSession.ModeDefault, out error);
            error = audioSession.SetActive(true, 
    AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.NotifyOthersOnDeactivation);

    audioSession.OverrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker, 
    out error);

            recognitionRequest = new SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest
            {
                ShouldReportPartialResults = true
            };

            var inputNode = audioEngine.InputNode;
            if (inputNode == null)
            {
                StaticHolder.ReportCrash("startDictating: ", new 
      NullReferenceException("Audio engine has no input node"));
                return;
            }

            if (speechRecognizer != null)
                recognitionTask = 
    speechRecognizer.GetRecognitionTask(recognitionRequest,
                    (result, err) => InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {

                var isFinal = false;

                if (result != null)
                {
                    isFinal = result.Final;
                    voiceResult = result.BestTranscription.FormattedString;
                    lblVoiceRecogResult.Text = voiceResult;
                    if (PreferenceClass.VoiceInstantSearch)
                    {
                        if (!stopRecognizer)
                        {
                            if (speechTimer != null)
                            {
                                speechTimer.Stop();
                                speechTimer.Start();
                            }
                            if (speechTimer == null)
                            {
                                speechTimer = new Timer();
                                speechTimer.Interval = 3000;
                                speechTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
                                {
                                    ((Timer)s).Stop();
                                    InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                                    {

    SoundEngine.Instance.PlaySound(AudioFilesType.Multiple);
                                        stopDictating();
                                        btnRecordDone_Clicked(null);
                                    });

                                    return;
                                };
                                speechTimer.Start();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //if (err != null || isFinal)
                //{
                //    if (PreferenceClass.VoiceInstantSearch)
                //    {
                //        stopDictating();
                //        HandleSpeechToTextResult();
                //    }
                //}
            }));

           inputNode.RemoveTapOnBus(0);
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438219/terminating-app-due-to- 
    uncaught-app-crashes-while-using-speech-kit-ios
            /*
            var recordingFormat = new AVAudioFormat(sampleRate: 44100, 
    channels: 1);
            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41805381/avaudioengine- 
    inputnode-installtap-crash-when-restarting-recording
            But it generated a crash again - 'required condition is false: 
    format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate'
            So used GetBusOutPutFormat
            */
            var recordingFormat = inputNode.GetBusOutputFormat(0);
            inputNode.InstallTapOnBus(
                        bus: 0,
                        bufferSize: 1024,
                        format: recordingFormat,
                        tapBlock: (buffer, when) => 
    recognitionRequest?.Append(buffer));
            audioEngine.Prepare();
            audioEngine.StartAndReturnError(out error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StaticHolder.ReportCrash("try to get voice record task 
    exception:", ex);
        }
    }


    private void stopDictating()
    {
        try
        {
            stopRecognizer = true;
            audioEngine.Stop();
            audioEngine.InputNode.RemoveTapOnBus(0);                
            recognitionRequest?.EndAudio();
            recognitionTask = null;
            recognitionRequest = null;                
            if (voiceTapNotification != null) NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(voiceTapNotification);
            if (searchTapNotification != null) NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(searchTapNotification);
            viewRecording.Hidden = true;                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StaticHolder.ReportCrash("try to stop voice record exception:", ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the user on a phone call when the crash occurs?

Comment: I removed the audioSession.SetCategor and audioSession.SetMode lines and the crash went away.

Answer (score 7):

It took me weeks to work out why this was happening in my MacOS app.  You have to enable the "Audio Input" capability in the project settings.

Comment: How to add Audio Input capability?  TARGETS->Sigin & Capability -> +capability then add ?

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have an input mic connected.**You might be running your app in a Mac mini with no mic connected.** You won't face this issue if it is an iPhone or iPad or mac with input mic connected.